# Recursive call of `val` in scala trait?

Tags: scala

I am trying to debug a scala program. I found a trait which behavior is similar to following:

```
trait A {
    val a: Int = b
    val b: Int = a
}

class B extends A
```

If we look at the trait there is cyclic assignment. `val` `b` is not even defined but used in definition of `val` `a`.

The above program compile successfully. Both `a` and `b` is `zero`. I tried to the same with variable type string and then value was `null`.

There is a third class that override `val a` similar to following

```
class C extends A {
    override val a: Int = 10
}
```

Now if an instance of class `C` is created value `a` is 10 but `val` of `b` is still `0`.

Finally, I checked further and instead of overriding a in the body of class, when I override it in constructor parameter similar to following:

```
class D(override val a: Int) extends A
val d = new D(10)
```

then both `d.a` and `d.b` is initialized to 10.

I wanted to understand that:

> 1. How definition of `val` in `trait A` is valid? In other words how scala interprets the `val` assignment in `trait A`
> 2. When a `val` that is defined in a trait is overridden in the body of a scala class what value is being used in the body of the trait if the same val is used in the trait elsewhere

Comment: Have you read: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html?